# Sat nav with windows CE and iGO

Tags: windows-ce

I have a GPS 84H-3 sat nav which runs on windows CE. It uses iGO for navigation.

The interface has an icon which opens the Windows CE desktop. It appears to give unrestricted access to the file system. It has reader versions of various MS office programs; other than that it seems to serve no purpose.

I have 3 questions:

1. Why would the manufacturer leave access to the desktop in the devices interface?
2. Is it possible to download and run an updated version of iGO on the machine (I found that the existing iGO version has a icon in the programs folder and the non-Windows interface has a app which lets me set the file the system runs when I click on the navigation icon; remember that the file system is accessible)
3. Is it possible to run alternative navigation software on the machine?

Answer (score 0):

this question is not well suited to Stack Overflow, but I will try to answer:

1) to allow users to run other programs, simply to make this device more user friendly.

2) probably yes, I suggest you ask iGO for any updates to your software

3) I suppose yes, but you must be aware that navigation software very often needs some form of integration with device, ie. it should take over the sound subsystem of your device while generating navigation voices, it should allow to switch between device UI interface and back to navigation, etc. This might need some changes from navigation software side (like usage of device API).

Answer (score 0):

Be aware than an embedded OS like Windows CE isn't the same as a desktop OS.  The application is likely part of the OS and it's quite likely that you cannot replace it without replacing the entire OS, which would have to come from the device OEM.  You might be able to "hide" the existing app with a new one, but it's also possible that any replacement will get lost when the device is restarted.

Running any other applications (a replacement navigation app or other) would depend on a lot of things.  The app would have to be built for CE.  The OS would have to have any dependencies the app needs.  The app would have to "understand" or be configurable for any peripherals you may need to use (like the GPS).

It may be possible to install apps or override behavior, but it's completely up to the device OEM on how they implemented things.  They have the choice of blocking all apps but the one(s) they want which would give you zero ability to do anything, or they may have left it wide open.  Short of some formal documentation from them, testing would be the only way to know for sure.

Comment: It seams that I am able to run other satnav software on it/

I have run a different piece of satnav software from the SD card (I have not tried deleteing the old software) and it works fine

I was also able to replace the maps and voice files for both the original software and the new software (the maps were a bit out of date)

furthermore the standard user interface has an icon which changes the file which the navigation icon opens, this is not hidden in any way and would be obvious even to technophobe user.

I am also able to run both programs from the Windows CE file explorer.